# When to prioritize accuracy over precision?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, accuracy, model-evaluations

I am working on a simple SVM project for the prediction of hepatitis c. I got my dataset from kaggle. When dealing with null values, I tried two ways, firstly by dropping data with null values, second by filling null values with mean.

[image]

The above is the result of the first method. I obtained a fairly high accuracy value, as well as a high precision value for blood donors (healthy people).However, the accuracy value of fibrosis, hepatitis, and suspect is 0. I know this because there are only a few datasets for these three categories, and some of them have null values, so they have to be dropped.

[image]

Next is if I replace the null value with the mean of the column. I get a slightly lower accuracy value, but still get precision on fibrosis and hepatitis. I want to know, is it more important to get high accuracy from dropping data, or precision from using mean values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it's important to realize that these two tables are not comparable, because the two models are not evaluated on the same dataset: in the first case you remove instances which contain undefined values, probably making it easier to predict the remaining instances. In particular it's clear that the 4 small classes are harder to find for the classifier, but in the first case you have only 9 instances from these classes instead of 14. This is a bias: by removing the difficult instances, the model can easily perform better.

Accuracy is pointless in a case like this where data is highly imbalanced: by always predicting the majority class the classifier reaches more than 90% accuracy. The precision/recall/f1-score measures are much more informative. You may notice that your macro F1-score is actually better in the second case, even though the dataset is harder with the undefined values.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

- To select your metric. First look into what is important for you? And Is the data balanced or not?
- If the data is balanced over all the categories of labels then you can choose `accuracy` as your metric.
- But it's not balanced, then you can select `precision`, `recall` or `f1-score`.
- Let me give you a simple example that will explain you about precision and recall. **You might think in terms of a smoke detector. High recall means the device catches most of the fires, while low recall means the device misses many fires. High precision means that, when the alarm goes off, you should believe there to be a fire, while low precision means that you might not be so inclined to believe there is a fire. “Ignore it, rings all the time without there being a fire,” you might say.**
- Now hopefully you can easily select your metric. And if you want to get good precision and good recall, then you should go with `f1-score`.

Hope I answered your question.